429 Too Many Requests error
As the Solana blockchain is already so fast, it's frustrating to keep encountering the 429 Too Many Requests error. How can we sync quickly with this public node? I'm using their own https://api.testnet.solana.com from their website. Is there anything I'm missing? Please suggest.

The public RPC nodes

https://api.testnet.solana.com
https://api.devnet.solana.com
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

are heavily rate limited and should not be used in production. There are many RPC providers that offer RPC services with higher rate limits.
For example, triton, helius, quicknode, hellomoon, alchemy and many more.

Our solution at Backpac.xyz can help you reduce the amount of 429's you experience by using multiple RPC endpoints.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
